# Finitely $\mu$-measurable sets are the closure of elementary sets

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am struggling to understand the next sentences from Principles of Mathematical Analysis, pp. 306.

> But if we define two sets $A$ and $B$ to be equivalent, provided
>   \begin{equation}
> d(A, B) = 0
> \end{equation}
>   we divide the subsets of $R^p$ into equivalence classes, and $d(A,B)$ makes the set of these equivalence classes into a metric space. $\mathscr{M}_F(\mu)$ is then obtained as the closure of $\mathscr{E}$.

The last sentence bothers me in some cases. As in the example above those sentences, if $A$ is countable and $B$ is empty or finite, then $d(A,B) = 0$, so they belong to the same equivalence class. Obviously, $A \notin \mathscr{E}$ and $B \in \mathscr{E}$ because an elementary set is a finite union of intervals. Since there exists a sequence $\{B_i\}$ of finite sets $B_i \in \mathscr{E}$ such that $B_i \to A$, we get $A \in \mathscr{M}_F(\mu) - \mathscr{E}$. Thus, an equivalence class has intersections with both $\mathscr{E}$ and $\mathscr{M}_F(\mu)$. Then, how can we say that $\mathscr{M}_F(\mu)$ is the closure of $\mathscr{E}$ on the set of equivalence classes with the metric $d(A,B)$?

Answer (score 0):

As one started to accept equivalence classes, any countable set $A$ is in the equivalence class $[\emptyset]$. So, from now on, all the sets $B\setminus A$ or $B\cup A$ where $A$ is a countable set are in the same class with $[B]$.  It seems to be a problem of logic. If $A\in [\emptyset],$ you can say a lot of things about $A$ which is logically true. From now on, we regard $d([A],[B])$ as $d(U,V)$, where $U\in[A], V\in[B].$